# Mirroring rotated object

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm attempting to mirror the orange cube to the other side, the rotation opposite, remaining the same dimensions. Any help?

Comment: Without knowing HOW you'r trying to mirror the object, not really! However, if you showed the whole screen with the mirror modifier settings and/or upload your blend file we might be able to help. - First thought (and the usual mistake lots of people make) is to make sure that the modifier is set to mirror on the Y axis rather than the X which is the default setting.

Comment: You can also use that large cube in the middle as a mirror target object, which will make your smaller one appear exactly the proportions you want.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1maHk0lGHd4tj0qVBHPOTHsnBIygKwJti/view?usp=sharing here's my file - sorry I wasn't as descriptive - I'm fairly new to blender...

Comment: Ok. You don't actually have a mirror modifier on your object at the moment, just a Subdivision one. Add a mirror modifier to your 'eye' object, click the little white square in the modifier's 'Mirror Object' field and then 'Cube' (which is your head) in the dropdown that appears. That will mirror the 'eye' to the other side as you want. I find it's a good idea to rename your objects as you add them so that you can keep track of what's what in the outliner otherwise you'll have a whole list of 'Cube.00x' objects and won't know which to select.